# Displaying a "User control is loading" message while loading a User Control

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I have a Winforms Application with a TabStrip Control. During runtime, UserControls are to be loaded into different tabs dynamically.

I want to present a "User Control xyz is loading" message to the user (setting an existing label to visible and changing its text) before the UserControl is loaded and until the loading is completely finished.

My approaches so far:

1. Trying to load the User Control in a BackgroundWorker thread. This fails, because I have to access Gui-Controls during the load of the UserControl
2. Trying to show the message in a BackgroundWorker thread. This obviously fails because the BackgroundWorker thread is not the UI thread ;-)
3. Show the Message, call DoEvents(), load the UserControl. This leads to different behaviour (flickering, ...) everytime I load a UserControl, and I can not control when and how to set it to invisible again.

To sum it up, I have two questions:

1. How to ensure the message is visible directly, before loading the User control
2. How to ensure the message is set to invisible again, just in the moment the UserControl is completely loaded (including all DataBindings, grid formattings, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what we use is similar to this:

1. create a new form that has whatever you want to show the user,
2. implement a static method where you can call this form to be created inside itself, to prevent memory leaks
3. create a new thread within this form so that form is running in a seperated thread and stays responsive; we use an ajax control that shows a progress bar filling up.

within the method you use to start the thread set its properties to topmost true to ensure it stays on top.

for instance do this in your main form:

```
loadingForm.ShowLoadingScreen("usercontrollname");
//do something
loadingform.CloseLoadingScreen();
```

in the loading form class;

```
public LoadingScreen()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}

public static void ShowLoadingScreen(string usercontrollname)
{
  // do something with the usercontroll name if desired
  if (_LoadingScreenThread == null)
  {
    _LoadingScreenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoShowLoadingScreen));
    _LoadingScreenThread.IsBackground = true;
    _LoadingScreenThread.Start();
  }
}

public static void CloseLoadingScreen()
{
  if (_ls.InvokeRequired)
  {
    _ls.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(CloseLoadingScreen));
  }
  else
  {
    Application.ExitThread();
    _ls.Dispose();
    _LoadingScreenThread = null;
  }
}

private static void DoShowLoadingScreen()
{
    _ls = new LoadingScreen();
    _ls.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    _ls.MinimizeBox = false;
    _ls.ControlBox = false;
    _ls.MaximizeBox = false;
    _ls.TopMost = true;
    _ls.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

  Application.Run(_ls);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works great as far as for the ShowLoadingScreen-part. The only thing I miss is finding the right event on the UserControl, where I can be sure it is completely loaded (and "UI-rendered") to call the CloseLoadingScreen()-part.

Comment: you could subscribe to an event that the usercontroll throws, but im not sure which one. i know the load event is triggered before the control is made visible for the first time, so maybe you could subcribe to the visible changed event to do this?

however, this does not check if your data is loaded. you could just write your own event handler and trigger the event the moment you done all the stuff you need in the loading part and use that as a work around.

Answer (score 1):

Try again your second approach:

> Trying to show the message in a BackgroundWorker thread. This obviously fails because the BackgroundWorker thread is not the UI thread ;-)

But this time, use the following code in your background thread in order to update your label:

```
label.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {
    label.Text = "User Control xyz is loading";
    label.Visible = true;
});
// Load your user control
// ...
label.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {
    label.Visible = false;
});
```

[`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) allows you to update your UI in another thread.

Answer (score 1):

Working from @wterbeek's example, I modified the class for my own purposes:

- center it over the loading form
- modification of its opacity
- sizing it to the parent size
- show it as a dialog and block all user interaction
- I was required to show a throbber

I received a null error on line:

```
if (_ls.InvokeRequired)
```

so I added a _shown condition (if the action completes so fast that the _LoadingScreenThread thread is not even run) to check if the form exists or not.

Also, if the _LoadingScreenThread is not started, Application.Exit will close the main thread.

I thought to post it for it may  help someone else. Comments in the code will explain more.

```
public partial class LoadingScreen : Form {

    private static Thread _LoadingScreenThread;

    private static LoadingScreen _ls;

    //condition required to check if the form has been loaded
    private static bool _shown = false;

    private static Form _parent;

    public LoadingScreen() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    //added the parent to the initializer
    //CHECKS FOR NULL HAVE NOT BEEN IMPLEMENTED
    public static void ShowLoadingScreen(string usercontrollname, Form parent) {
        // do something with the usercontroll name if desired
        _parent = parent;
        if (_LoadingScreenThread == null) {
            _LoadingScreenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoShowLoadingScreen));
            _LoadingScreenThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            _LoadingScreenThread.IsBackground = true;
            _LoadingScreenThread.Start();
        }
    }

    public static void CloseLoadingScreen() {
        //if the operation is too short, the _ls is not correctly initialized and it throws 
        //a null error
        if (_ls!=null && _ls.InvokeRequired) {
            _ls.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(CloseLoadingScreen));
        } else {
            if (_shown)
            {
                //if the operation is too short and the thread is not started
                //this would close the main thread
                _shown = false;
                Application.ExitThread();
            }
            if (_LoadingScreenThread != null)
                _LoadingScreenThread.Interrupt();
            //this check prevents the appearance of the loader
            //or its closing/disposing if shown
            //have not found the answer
            //if (_ls !=null)
            //{
               _ls.Close();
               _ls.Dispose();
            //}
            _LoadingScreenThread = null;
        }
    }

    private static void DoShowLoadingScreen() {
        _ls = new LoadingScreen();
        _ls.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        _ls.MinimizeBox = false;
        _ls.ControlBox = false;
        _ls.MaximizeBox = false;
        _ls.TopMost = true;
        //get the parent size
        _ls.Size = _parent.Size; 
        //get the location of the parent in order to show the form over the 
        //target form
        _ls.Location = _parent.Location;     
        //in order to use the size and the location specified above
        //we need to set the start position to "Manual"
        _ls.StartPosition =FormStartPosition.Manual;
        //set the opacity
        _ls.Opacity = 0.5;
        _shown = true;
        //Replaced Application.Run with ShowDialog to show as dialog
        //Application.Run(_ls);
        _ls.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```